# ios methods becoming zombies

Tags: ios

I added uiviewcontroller subclass in my arc enabled project, i added a button created the ibaction for it and inside it contains no code, all done through interface builder no manual code, but when i am tapping the button i am getting exc_bad_acess. Instrumentation saying its a zombie attack when pressing button. I really dont understand whats going wrong. I created the new project and done the same thing it is working perfectly. Same thing happening when i am defining method to dismiss keyboard (resign first responder).

this generated when i crtl+dragged from button to interface implementation, i choose the ibaction and name and this code is generated.

```
- (IBAction)pushh:(id)sender;
```

and the implementation inside .m file

```
- (IBAction)pushh:(id)sender {
}
```

thats all ...

Comment: this seems close to my problem but i am having difficulty understanding this please help me out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947923/view-based-nstableview-exc-bad-access-on-lion-with-arc

Comment: It's hard to diagnose why ARC would be releasing your object (thus becoming a zombie) without seeing the code. Please edit your original question to include the code and we'll see if we can help.

Comment: alrighty i am adding the code...thanks for replying...

Comment: please check the code and reply ....

Comment: Ok, check your File Owner's custom class (compare to your new project), and make sure you're referencing the right class for your view controller. Also, check the outlets for the button, to make sure they're ok. Also, how are you creating your view controller and displaying your view?

Comment: everything seems ok, i havnt created any outlet for button and when i created uiviewcontroller subclass i also choose the xib file, so every thing is created automatically. I just dragged the button and created the ibaction for it .... please have a look at this post i am having difficulty understanding this because it shows no code ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947923/view-based-nstableview-exc-bad-access-on-lion-with-arc

Comment: So, I'll ask (again) the same question that Chuck did in that other discussion: How are you creating your view controller and showing this view with the button? Can you show that code? Looks like Chuck asked that question and jbrennan looked at that code and found the problem...

Comment: :) ...     EnterContactNumber *ecnObj = [[EnterContactNumber alloc]init];
    
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ecnObj.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];

Comment: Hmm. I could easily imagine that ARC would conclude that ecnObj is going out of scope and therefore kindly release it for you (giving you your zombie). You could probably make it an ivar of view controller and it wouldn't get released on you. Personally, I'd even be wary of swapping out the main view of a view controller, but perhaps it works. So, both your EnterContactNumber view and the main view for that view controller have designated the same view controller class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10131/discussion-between-robert-ryan-and-pamy)

Answer (score 1):

Just to wrap up the offline conversation, a couple of thoughts:

1. Your zombie is undoubtedly a result of the ecnObj falling out of scope. If it's an ivar of the view controller, then that premature release problem goes away.
2. You do *not* want to create a new view controller and then use its view in `transitionFromView`. If you want to transition between view controllers (in iOS5) you should use `pushViewController` or `presentViewController` (or if you're using a container view controller, you can pursue `transitionFromViewController`). See View Controller Programming Guide's discussion of "[Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)".

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the button `iboutlet` in ib, also delete the `ibaction` in ib, and then connect it back.